# Error: insert enum identifier

Tags: java, syntax, enums, identifier

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code here and why I keep getting 'enum identifier error' ?

```
public static void app(){

        ArrayList<Integer> usedArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        usedArray.add(1);
        usedArray.add(2);

        Random generator = new Random ();

        private static void generator(){
        int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(usedArray.size());
        }

        System.out.println(randomNumber);

        if(randomNumber == 2){
            score();
            question2();
            usedArray.remove(2);
            generator();
        }
        if(randomNumber == 1){
            score();
            question1();
            usedArray.remove(1);
            generator();
        }

}

}
```

```
   Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
   Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
   Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
```

why do I get this error ? and what is an enum identifier ? Have checked all my brackets and they are all closed where appropiate

Comment: You can't just dump a method inside another method.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The probable reason for the "enum" error message is this: since the syntax of a method doesn't allow you to define another method inside it, the compiler is encountering something totally unexpected and then has to guess how to handle it.  It's apparently making some guess about what you were really trying to do, and it's guessing wrong.  You really can't expect error messages to make sense all the time when you're making such a major violation of the syntax rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing a method inside another method which is wrong:

```
public static void app(){

    // ...

    private static void generator(){
        int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(usedArray.size());
    }

    //..

}
```

Comment: but what if I want to make the randomNumber variable accessible between 2 methods ?

Comment: @LeoRickayzen 1. Define it as a local variable in one method and pass it to the other method, or 2. Define the variable as a static field.